# Accessing Mosaic Dataset Properties to Change Default Mosaic Operator using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, mosaic-dataset

I would like to change the default mosaic operator on mosaic datasets my script creates. However, I can only manually change the mosaic operator from mosaic dataset properties from ArcCatalog by right clicking the mosaic dataset. Is there a way this could be access and changed from the script itself?

This is the properties window that I am trying to access using arcpy:
[image]

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to this:

```
for mosaic_dataset in mosaic_datasets:
    arcpy.CreateMosaicDataset_management(gdb_path, mosaic_dataset, coord, "1","8_BIT_UNSIGNED")
```

which works fine, but the next step is to change the mosaic operator from python rather than manually changing it and I cannot find any documentation.

Comment: I've added the code, but there is no documentation on how to access mosaic dataset properties from python, so I have no idea how to code next step.

Comment: According to https://geonet.esri.com/thread/84146#comment-354355 there is no way to access the properties through python, you need to use arcobjects

Comment: You may need to consider looking for or submitting an ArcGIS Idea.

Comment: I found a workaround for this problem but this is good to know. Ty.

Comment: @cptpython there's a standard arcpy tool to do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Set Mosaic Dataset Properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/set-mosaic-dataset-properties.htm) tool.

```
arcpy.SetMosaicDatasetProperties_management(mosaic, default_mosaic_method='First')
```

You can set more than one property at a time:

```
arcpy.SetMosaicDatasetProperties_management(mosaic,
    allowed_compressions='NONE;LZ77',
    default_compression_type='LZ77',
    resampling_type='NEAREST',
    allowed_mensuration_capabilities='NONE',
    default_mensuration_capabilities='NONE',
    allowed_mosaic_methods='Center;LockRaster;ByAttribute;None',
    default_mosaic_method='ByAttribute',
    order_field='RANK',
    sorting_order=True,
    mosaic_operator='MIN',
    max_num_per_mosaic=500,
    metadata_level='BASIC',
    data_source_type='THEMATIC')
```

Comment: Wonderful! Shame on me for not digging hard enough.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for this problem was to create an empty mosaic dataset, make the desired changes and then place it in a loop using `arcpy.Copy_management` to create multiple copies. It is not ideal, but gets the job done with minimal reworking of workflow:

```
for mosaic_dataset in mosaic_datasets:
    mosaic_data_template = "C:/MD.gdb/template"     
    arcpy.Copy_management(mosaic_data_template, mosaic_dataset)
```